# Converse of the Urysohn metrization theorem

Tags: general-topology

Urysohn metrization theorem says that every regular and second countable topological space is metrizable. My question, is the converse of this theorem ture ? If not, what are the counter examples?

Any reply kindly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The converse of this theorem does not hold.

As an example consider the set of all real numbers $ \mathbb{R} $ with the discrete topology $ \tau_{d} $. Clearly $ (\mathbb{R},\tau_{d}) $ is metrizable and the discrete metric $ \rho_{d} $ is the metrization of $ \tau_{d} $. Also $ \mathbb{R} $ is regular with respect to $ \tau_{d} $ since every closed subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is open with respect to $ \tau_{d} $.

Notice that if a collection $ \mathcal{B} $ of subsets of $ \mathbb{R} $ is a base for $ (\mathbb{R},\tau_{d}) $ then $ \mathcal{B} $ contains $ \{\{x\}:x\in \mathbb{R}\} $. But $ \{\{x\}:x\in \mathbb{R}\} $ is uncountable. Hence $ \mathcal{B} $ is also uncountable. Therefore $ (\mathbb{R},\tau_{d}) $ has no countable base even though $ (\mathbb{R},\tau_{d}) $ is metrizable. Therefore the converse of the Urysohn metrization theorem does not hold.

Comment: All metric spaces are regular (in fact, perfectly normal), so the last sentence of the second paragraph is somewhat superfluous.

Comment: @ArthurFischer you are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

A metrizable space is second countable if and only if it is separable.There are many examples of non-separable metrizable spaces,e.g.,in the previous answer, the discrete topology on any uncountable set